# Convert List to JsonObject in Java using json simple

Tags: java, json, list, json-simple

I have a list -

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>;
```

which consists of items - **[firstname , abc , lastname , pqr , id , 1 ]**

I need to convert this list to JSONObject of below format in java using json simple lib -

**{"firstname":"abc","lastname":"pqr","id":"1"}**

How can I achieve this?
I am just a beginner.Any help would be appreciated.Thankyou in advance.

Comment: is the List data constant like you mentioned, first element is name, second element is its value, like wise on and on ???

Comment: Also, Can you please add the Code of Item Class ?

Comment: Is `Item` a `String` ? or some other kind of class ?

Comment: No,not constant.. I am getting the values in List from Bean Item by inputting values in TextFields.

Comment: Can you Put your Item Class structure? because you need to convert list to map and then to json.So It required to show how your Item class is exactly look like

Comment: Edited the question - Added Item.java and Bean.java

Comment: I need to add values of  **value** and **type** from getters in Item.java to List in Bean.java and convert to JsonObject of mentioned format.Already List is accessed in Bean.java. Please help regarding conversion to JSONObject of mentioned format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the answer -

First converted the List to Map and then to Json -

```
public Map<String, String> test() {

    Map<String, String> result = items.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getValue, Item::getType)); //Converts List items to Map

    System.out.println("Result  : " + result);

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result); //Converts MAP to JsonObject

    System.out.println("JSON : " + json); //prints {"firstname":"abc","lastname":"pqr","id":"1"}
    return result;
}
```